# Spill table column with specified number of blank rows between entries in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a cell based function that can spill the entries from a table column whilst inserting a defined number of blank rows between each entry?

For example, In the following image I have the function `=FILTER(DisciplineTbl, {1,0,0,0})` in cell P32:

[image: Disciplines]

In column S I have inserted what I am hoping to achieve, ideally through a formula in S32 that can spill the contents down the column with the specied empty rows between entries. Is something like this possible with a cell based formula or will it require a VBA solution?

Comment: Should be doable, but the formula spilling down from S32 will impede anything being written manually to S33, S34, S35... Is that a concern?

Comment: no concern, that's exactly what I'm after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=LET(
    ζ, A1:A4,
    δ, 5,
    ε, δ + 1,
    ξ, SEQUENCE(ε * ROWS(ζ) - δ, , 0),
    IF(MOD(ξ, ε), "", INDEX(ζ, 1 + QUOTIENT(ξ, ε)))
)
```

where `δ` (5 here) is the number of blank rows to be inserted between each entry.

`A1:A4` can of course be replaced with a dynamic spill range.